# Getting "net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed" exception in my java code during xslt transformation

Tags: java, xslt, stream, ioexception

I am using xslt along with java to process and convert input xml files to produce multiple result documents.
But I am getting below error at transformer.transform(input, output) in my java transformation class.

Please help me in this.

**Stack Trace:**

```
java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
    at net.sf.saxon.event.XMLEmitter.close(XMLEmitter.java:264)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ProxyReceiver.close(ProxyReceiver.java:90)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.UncommittedSerializer.close(UncommittedSerializer.java:53)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ImplicitResultChecker.close(ImplicitResultChecker.java:92)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ProxyReceiver.close(ProxyReceiver.java:90)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ComplexContentOutputter.close(ComplexContentOutputter.java:507)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:1848)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1621)
```

**Java code snippet:**

```
String outputDirectory = fileParentLocation + "\\resultFolder\\";
FileTools.createDirectory(new File(outputDirectory));

try {
TransformerFactory factory =
        TransformerFactory.newInstance("net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl", getClass().getClassLoader());

InputStream xsltResourceAsStream =
        getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("ConvertInputXmlFiles.xslt");
Source xslt = new StreamSource(xsltResourceAsStream);
Result output = new StreamResult(new File(outputDirectory + "test.xml"));
        
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
transformer.setParameter("versionName", versionName);        

  if (filesToBeTransformed != null && !filesToBeTransformed.isEmpty()) {
    for (File file : filesToBeTransformed) {
        Source input = new StreamSource(file);
        transformer.transform(input, output);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to append multiple transformation results to the same output stream, and that doesn't work.

I think it would probably work if you created a `FileOutputStream` and supplied that in the `StreamResult`, instead of supplying the `File`. Basically, whoever creates a stream is responsible for closing it, and if you supply a `File`, then Saxon creates the stream, and will close it at the end of the transformation, but if you create the stream, then you can choose whether to close it or not.

Your prose question says you're trying to produce multiple output documents, but your code seems to be trying to produce a single result document. Which is it?

Note also, with Saxon we recommend doing `TransformerFactory.newTemplates()` once to compile the stylesheet, and then creating a new `Transformer` for each transformation using `Templates.newTransformer()`. Serial reuse of a single `Transformer` is allowed, but may cause unnecessary accumulation of resources in internal caches.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried it, but it did not resolve my issue. As you said, I am not creating multiple files through java, but I am generating multiple files through xslt inside `outputDirectory` location.

Comment: So what did you change? My advice is that you don't attempt to reuse the same StreamResult for multiple transformations.